# For f(x) = ((3x+7)^8)((4x-5)^3) , find f'(x) and use this answer to find the value(s) of x at which the graph of f(x) has a horizontal tangent line

Tags: derivatives, binomial-coefficients

I know that $f'(x) = (24(3+7)^7)*(4x-5)^3+((3x+7)^8)*12(4x-5)^2$, but is there any easier way to find the horizontal tangent line without expanding the terms using pascal's triangle and solving for x by setting f'(x) equal to 0?

Answer (score 1):

your derivative can be factorized into $$12 (3 x+7)^7 (4 x-5)^2 (11 x-3)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

f(x) = $(3x+7)^8 * (4x-5)^3$

log(f(x)) =  $8log(3x+7) + 3log(4x-5)$

Now take the derivative and get the required answer. It's a one-two step process.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=(3x+7)^8(4x-5)^3$$
$$f'(x)=8(3x+7)^7.3(4x-5)^3+(3x+7)^83.(4x-5)^2.4$$
$$f'(x)=(3x+7)^7(4x-5)^2[24(4x-5)+12(3x+7)]$$
$$f'(x)=(3x+7)^7(4x-5)^2[132x-36]$$
$$f'(x)=12(3x+7)^7(4x-5)^2[11x-3]$$
to find the tangent point 
$$(3x+7)^7=0$$
$$(4x-5)^2=0$$
$$(11x-3)=0$$